# How to install tomcat7 in docker ?

Tags: docker, devops

i installed  docker in my QA environment (ubuntu 14.04) which has already installed with tomcat7 and java.can i install tomcat7 and java using docker pull command  in command line and can i deploy same application on this docker?

`

[enter image description here

`

Comment: sorry whether i am correct or not?

Comment: look at the tomcat available in the docker hub `https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=tomcat&starCount=0`

Comment: Thank you so much to stack overflow and user29150975

Answer (score 0):

[Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) has already provided an tomcat images, you don't have to start from scratch and here is how:

```
docker pull tomcat:8.0

docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 --name foo tomcat:8.0
```